# I’m converting PDFs to ePubs using calibre, it is very slow can you suggest faster alternatives?

Tags: big-sur, ebook

Problem:

converting pdfs to epubs using calibre is very slow. It has takes 2 hours+ for 40mb pdfs to convert to epub

I’m using calibre to convert from PDFs to ePub format for books but it is exceedingly slow.

Question:

Is there a faster app I can use that you have tested vs calibre and found the performance much better?

Research:

I looked online for alternatives but they all seem like ads pushing their product, so I thought it best to ask the community who won’t have a financial incentive and will have experience.

System:
MacBook Air 2018 model

Processor:
1.6GHz dual-core Intel Core i5

Storage1:
128GB PCIe-based SSD

OS:
Big Sur latest update (yesterday)

Comment: Converting from PDF to ePub is a lot of work. You've got to generate HTML-style tags to match the layout of the PDF page. Your CPU is 'not the fastest'. A 40Mb PDF of text and graphics is quite large.

Comment: Ok @benwiggy, I’m just asking is the performance among all apps therefore going to be similar?

Comment: @Nickotine You might see fractional improvements, depending on implementation, but it still going to take hours.

Comment: Some of the alternatives seem to be free, maybe just try one? It took a few minutes to convert a 40MB PDF on an M1, with one CPU core at 100%. This easily explains why it takes ages on the CPU in your Mac. Unless there are apps out there which can use several CPU cores in parallel for this you most likely will not see significant improvements.

Comment: Tyvm @nohillside that’s just the kind of knowledge I needed to know I just thought it was the apps fault I didn’t know it is cpu dependent

Comment: @benwiggy is it possible to upgrade the cpu on a MacBook Air?

Comment: @Nickotine No: it's soldered to the logic board. nohillside's point is that the brand new M1 Macs are insanely fast compared to the old Intel ones, so 'a few minutes' can easily translate to 2 hours on yours. How many ePub books are you planning to make? Do you have access to the original documents that the PDFs were made from? Apps like InDesign can export directly to Epub much more quickly.

Comment: @benwiggy I’ll give indesign a try thank you

Comment: @benwiggy I'm going to have to pass on indesign because you need to give your card details...

Comment: @Nickotine, well, yes it's a commercial app. I only suggested it as an example of the type of application likely to have been used in creating the PDFs that you have. If you don't have the original documents that made the PDF, then InDesign won't help you. Can you tell us more about the files you have, where they came from, what you're trying to do with them, etc.

Comment: Ok so a guy in the software recommendations suggested I use the cmd line version, so here is the comparison for the identical pdf 30.1mb: GUI convert to ePub=1hr47mins, terminal convert to ePub=37 mins I used the `time` and the ePub works fine highly recommend the cmdline version

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the original PDF to test here [with promise to bin it afterwards if there is a copyright issue] on an old Mac Pro 3.46GHz dual 6-core Xeon, Calibre turned a 20MB pdf into an EPub [at default settings, which may or may not be ideal] in under a minute . I'm aware my random pdf may not be vaguely comparable.

Comment: sure, keep it if you want it's just some old chemistry book, give me a sec

Comment: your old MacBook Pro is more powerful than mine... mines is a 2018 model MacBook Air, I'm just thinking of how I can upload it... not sure if I have to pay for my dropbox... might use GitHub I'll be a min @tetsujin, just remember to do them separately and use the `time` command when running the cmdline version

Comment: Ugh, yeah, definitely single-threaded… this might take a while… :\

Comment: @Tetsujin. let me know if it's the same for you when you get a chance to test it

Comment: I stared at it for about 40 minutes, after which it still said 1%, at which point I decided life was too short ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the identical 30mb pdf book:

Calibre GUI: 1hr47 mins to convert

Calibre cmdline: 37 mins to convert

The GUI converted ePub is in the calibre library dir

The cmdline converted ePub is in the calibre cmdline dir

Both working as expected

Steps:

`cd ~/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS`

Test for yourself with:

`time ./ebook-convert <pathToPdf>.pdf <pathWhereEver>.epub`

Compare with GUI convert and be amazed

Add the following to `~/.bash_profile` so you can just do `ebook-convert`:

`export PATH=“/Users/$HOME/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS:$PATH”`